# Aggregation Error at Sitecore.Commerce.ExperienceAnalytics.Models.CartLineModel

Tags: sitecore-commerce

Processing server logs are full of the error

```
Aggregation Error
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.SegmentProcessor.ProcessSegments(AggregationPipelineArgs args, IEnumerable`1 segments)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.SegmentProcessor.OnProcess(AggregationPipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.AggregationProcessor.Process(AggregationPipelineArgs args)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.Commerce.ExperienceAnalytics
   at Sitecore.Commerce.ExperienceAnalytics.Models.CartLineModel.GetKey()
   at System.Linq.Lookup`2.Create[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable`3.GetEnumerator()
   at Sitecore.Commerce.ExperienceAnalytics.Dimensions.ByCartManipulationsBase.<GetData>d__2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.SegmentProcessor.ProcessSegments(AggregationPipelineArgs args, IEnumerable`1 segments)
```

I have registered the types in a pipeline processor that are patched after *Sitecore.Analytics.Outcome.Pipelines.Initialize.RegisterDataModelExtensions*

```
 patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Analytics.Outcome.Pipelines.Initialize.RegisterDataModelExtensions, Sitecore.Analytics.Outcome']" />
```

and in my pipeline processor, I have the code to register the classes:

```
MongoDbObjectMapper.Instance.RegisterModelExtension<CartInfo>();
MongoDbObjectMapper.Instance.RegisterModelExtension<CartLineInfo>();
```

Is there anything else that I need to do?

Comment: are you getting these error only when you are applying the patch, or the errors are present without patch also?<br/><br/>
There are errors related to Sitecore commerce as well, you might need to check the setup of application once again and see the basic setup is in place.

Comment: Did you make sure that all the definitions have been deployed? Check if they are not in draft mode and they have been deployed